# BLDC motor and torque reverse of rotation

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, gear

I am designing a hoist style system that uses a BLDC motor, worm gearbox, and sprocket to lift and lower a load.

parameters

- motor 400W, 1.3Nm rated, 3000 rpm (only will be used to 2000)
- gearbox, 1:40 ratio, ~60-70% efficient
- load 28Nm torque, (motor and gearbox will output 30.6-35.6Nm)
- back-driven load, uncertain. maybe can assume as a worst case it will be 28Nm * 1/40 * .7 = .49 Nm torque. although other estimates say that the worm drive will be unable to be back-driven.

the two conditions I am concerned about are as such, using worst case torque estimates

1. When the motor is holding the load, 0 rpm, +.49Nm torque
2. When the motor is lowering the load -2000rpm, +.49Nm torque

I was looking at motor controllers and started to get confused, I believe I need a 4 quadrant motor controller in order to lower the load while providing torque opposite that of rotation, this is a bit outside my wheelhouse of mechanical design.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great

to summarize, is this an appropriate use of a BLDC motor, is a standard controller acceptable or do I need a 4 quadrant controller.

Thank you

Comment: I think the holding torque is actually an explicit part of the typical specifications for a BLDC motor. For example, each motor [here](https://www.ato.com/high-torque-bldc-motors) lists its holding torque. I found [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323683147_The_sensitivity_of_the_hoist_system_in_crane_applications_from_speed_control_methods_at_induction_motorDie_Empfindlichkeit_des_Hebesystems_bei_Krananwendungen_von_den_Geschwindigkeitsregelverfahren_am) covering more than a few thoughts I had in back of mind. Maybe it helps you or offers clues for further searching?

Comment: If it is being backdriven, then the motor needs to operate as a generator. This means that yes, you need a four-quadrant controller, and that you also need to dissipate the energy generated somehow - if you have a battery you might be able to guarantee there's extra capacity; otherwise you'll need a braking resistor.

Comment: Worm drives usually can't be backdriven, but the easiest way to find out is probably to put a spanner on the output shaft and see if you can turn it.

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for the advice on that, that's the exact supplier Im using for the motor, I noticed the holding torque but then got confused because a bunch of the specs were listed wrong on their website and one supplier of motor controllers said our motor would burn up at 0RPM. Ill see if i can make sense of that article too thanks!

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica Ok that sounds good, it seems i need to google "regenerative BLDC motor controller" to find 4 quadrant controllers, still hard to find them though.

indeed most worm drives cant usually be backdriven, im concerned that once it starts moving, the dynamic friction * low ratio will be enough for it to keep moving though. once we have it in hand itll be easier to see